# OpenGL: draw line between two elements

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics, line

I need to draw a line between two meshes I've created. Each mesh is associated with a different model matrix. I've been thinking on how to do this and I thought of this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(first_object_model_matrix);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // object coord
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(first_object_model_matrix);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // ending point of the line
glEnd( );
```

But the problem is that I can't call `glMatrixMode` and `glLoadMatrixf` between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. I'm also using shaders and the programmable pipeline, so the idea of turning back to the fixed pipeline with my scene rendered isn't exciting.

Can you:

- Suggest me precisely how to draw a line between two meshes (I have their model matrix) with shaders.

or

- Suggest me how to write code similar to the one above to draw a line having two meshes model matrices.

Comment: The only way I've done it is to multiply the coordinates by their respective matrices, and then draw the line using an identity modelview matrix.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't calculate and store the line points before the rendering stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate the line's two points by multiplying each one with one of your model matrices. The following is pseudo-code. Since you're using Qt, you could use its built-in maths libraries to accomplish this effect.

```
vec3 line_point_1 = model_matrix_object1 * vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
vec3 line_point_2 = model_matrix_object2 * vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
// Draw Lines
```

Answer (score 1):

The position of the second point can simply be taken from the w vector of the model_matrix_object2. No need to multiply with (0,0,0,1).

This is because a 4x4 matrix in OpenGL is usually an ortho matrix consisting of a 3x3 rotational part and a translational vector. The last row is then padded with 0,0,0,1. If you want to know where a 4x4 matrix would translate simply get the vector in the right-most column.

See [Given a 4x4 homogeneous matrix, how can i get 3D world coords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791710/given-a-4x4-homogeneous-matrix-how-can-i-get-3d-world-coords) for more info.

Comment: I dont' get it, can you explain a little better?